# How to print two tables in one line of a word document

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

How can you print two R matrices as two tables to a word document but in one line (side by side)?

**Example Code**

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
a <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),nrow=3, ncol=2)
rownames(a) <- c("A", "B", "C")
colnames(a) <- c("C1", "C2")
b <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2, ncol=2)
rownames(b) <- c("A", "B")
colnames(b) <- c("C2", "C3")
kable(a)
kable(b)

# Or CL.'s example
dat <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:8], 1:8)
dat2 <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:10], 1:10)
kable(a)
kable(b)
```
````

Comment: The purpose is to generate tables with different row length. So cbind can be used, but then the look and feel can not be changed, so that the two tables can be differed from each other.

Comment: @Tensibai I suppose something like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d59bda45e6046543908c) but with the two tables side by side. b4154: Feel free to add this example to your question.

Comment: @CL I believe it's OP responsibility to craft a proper question with a [mcve], it's a matter of respect to those taking on their time to answer IMO :)

Comment: @Tensibai I agree, but in this case the question seems to be clear (assuming that my understanding of it is correct): Print two tables, side by side, in a word document.

Comment: @CL. : yes, you are right.

Comment: Now you can see an example and also CL. example.

Comment: I don't know "r" or what it can do, but I can tell you about Tables in Word, which might help... Word can only position tables side-by-side if they're "floating". This means either 1) text wrap formatting is applied to the tables or 2) the tables are placed in a FRAME (not to be confused with a webpage frame) or a TextBox (the drawing kind). This kind of positioning is tricky and not really reliable. Besides that, you could create a one-row, two-column table and NEST these tables each in a cell of that table. If "r" will let you do any of these, my choice would be the last: nested tables.

Comment: Nested table was my first idea too, unfortunately `kable` is not capable of this according to it's doc and example [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/091-knitr-table.Rnw),

Comment: @ Cindy: I think I understand what you mean. But I do not know how to create the nested tables. using a `list` creates one table in word document where the two matrices are connected by rows. Look at the result: l <- list(dat, dat2)
kable(l)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a hacky workaround than a clean solution but maybe it is still helpful. Note that I do **not** recommend this for HTML output (in that case, there are better solutions) but only as a workaround for Word output.

The problem is, the `markdown → pandoc → Word` chain doesn't allow for much control over the final output. Templates might be a way out of this limitation but in this answer I just use a simple trick: Instead of printing two tables side by side, print one big table, containing all data. The two "sub-tables" are separated by an empty column of variable width.

(10 seconds before posting this I realized that the horiztonal line below the header should probably be split. I have no clue how to achieve this.)

To keep as much of the convenience of `knitr::kable` as possible, I use the output of `kable` as input and merge the two tables together. This is a little bit tricky in cases where one table has more rows than the other. Then the shorter table needs to be padded with empty cells. This needs to be done on the "text level" (i.e. the raw markdown that `kable` returns). Adjusting the length of the input data by adding `NA` rows before feeding it to `kable` would result in visible `NA`s in the output.

```
PrintSideBySide <- function(kabled1, kabled2, spaces = 1, fillerChar = "&nbsp;") {
  # Generate string of protected spaces.
  filler = paste(rep(fillerChar, times = spaces), collapse = "")

  # Add empty rows to "shorter" in order to get equal number of rows.
  expandShorter <- function(shorter, longer) {
    toAdd <- length(longer) - length(shorter)
    extraRows <- gsub(pattern = "[^\\|]", replacement = " ", x = shorter[1])
    return(c(shorter, rep(extraRows, times = toAdd)))
  }

  if (length(kabled1) < length(kabled2)) {
    kabled1 <- expandShorter(kabled1, kabled2)
  } else {
    kabled2 <- expandShorter(kabled2, kabled1)
    # If length is equal, expandShorter doesn't modify kabled2.
  }

  # Print, row by row.
  for (i in seq_along(kabled1)) {
    cat(kabled1[i]) # Print row i of first table.
    cat(" ")
    if (i != 2) { 
      cat(filler) # Print whitespace in row i.
    } else {
      cat(paste(rep("-", times = nchar(filler)), collapse = "")) # In the second row, print a separator between header and body. 
    }
    cat(" ")
    cat(kabled2[i]) # Print row i of second table
    cat("\n")
  }
}
```

An example of use would be:

```
library(knitr)
dat <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:8], 1:8)
dat2 <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:10], 1:10)
PrintSideBySide(kable(dat), kable(dat2), spaces = 5)

  # |LETTERS.1.8. | X1.8| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |LETTERS.1.10. | X1.10|
  # |:------------|----:| ------------------------------ |:-------------|-----:|
  # |A            |    1| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |A             |     1|
  # |B            |    2| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |B             |     2|
  # |C            |    3| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |C             |     3|
  # |D            |    4| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |D             |     4|
  # |E            |    5| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |E             |     5|
  # |F            |    6| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |F             |     6|
  # |G            |    7| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |G             |     7|
  # |H            |    8| &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |H             |     8|
  # |             |     | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |I             |     9|
  # |             |     | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; |J             |    10|
```

Note that `kable` is intentionally called outside `PrintSideBySide`. This leaves the possibility to set argumens like `align` or `row.names` as desired. However, beware of setting a `caption`, this will break the table.

The `results` from `PrintSideBySide` must be printed [`asis`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options).

Below a reproducible example. Please insert the definition of `PrintSideBySide` from above.

````
---
title: "Print Tables Side By Side"
output: word_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
library(knitr)
dat <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:8], 1:8)
dat2 <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:10], 1:10)

PrintSideBySide <- function(kabled1, kabled2, spaces = 1, fillerChar = "&nbsp;") {
## Insert function definition here ##
}

PrintSideBySide(kable(dat), kable(dat2), spaces = 80)
```
````

[image: Output]